# Spark SQL get lineage of parent tables

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have created 3 temporary tables from loading from case class. And let's call it

- **ABC**
- **BCD**
- **EFG**

Then I proceed to created 3 more tables by performing join.

- **ABC** join with **BCD** which gives **XYZ**
- **XYZ** join with **EFG** which gives **LMN**
- **LMN** join with **ABC** which gives **PQR**

Does spark allow me in some way to see the lineage of dependent registered temporary table?? How can I extract the information where it knows LMN depends on XYZ and PQR depends on LMN, and use it programmatically to build a lineage tree (without all the plan information). 
etc:

```
 |-PQR
    |-LMN
        |-XYZ
           |- ABC
        |-EFG
    |-ABC
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean something like `DataFrame.explain`?

Comment: I have tried dataframe.explain, does not show you the lineage table

Comment: Did you use `extended=true`?

Comment: Yes, it does with extended. However, I want to be able use the information programmatically instead of just printing it. I will update the question to be specific.

Comment: Then you have a lot coding ahead of you :) I could be wrong but as far as l can tell it won't be possible without modifying DataFrame code and rebuilding Spark from scratch.

Comment: @zero323 is right! Specially since they added the Tungsten project.

Comment: @eliasah What do you think http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310265/1560062?

Comment: Thanks. At least I asked.

Comment: you can try spline

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source tool you can use to visualize the lineage: https://github.com/AbsaOSS/spline

It harvests the lineages at the runtime and captures it to display as a graph.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this SQL for example, which exactly creates the table/view as you mentioned.

```sql
CREATE TABLE ABC(abc_column1 int, abc_column2 string);
CREATE TABLE BCD(bcd_column1 int, bcd_column2 string);
CREATE TABLE EFG(efg_column1 int, efg_column2 string);

create view XYZ(xyz_column1,xyz_column2) 
as select abc.abc_column1, bcd.bcd_column2
from abc 
left join bcd on abc.abc_column1 = bcd.bcd_column1;
  
create view LMN (lmn_column1,lmn_column2)
as select xyz.xyz_column1, efg.efg_column2
from xyz 
left join efg on xyz.xyz_column1 = efg.efg_column1;

create view PQR (pqr_column1, pqr_column2)
as select lmn.lmn_column1, abc.abc_column2
from LMN 
left join ABC on abc.abc_column1 = lmn.lmn_column1;
```

And this is the data lineage that you are asking:
[image: SQLFlow data lineage]

You may try your own SQL to get the data lineage here:
https://sqlflow.gudusoft.com/#/